# List files, filtered by extension without path

Tags: vb.net, list, listbox, format, getfiles

Due difficulties to filter and list several types of files in the same line of code, like this: `System.IO.directory.getfiles(path, "*.avi, *.flv, *mpg"` I'm using a sorted ListBox and the next code with one line for each format:

```
Dim newdir As String
 ListBox3.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(newdir, "*.avi"))
 ListBox3.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(newdir, "*.flv"))
 ListBox3.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(newdir, "*.mpg"))
```

This code list alphabetically just known VIDEO files, the only issue: It lists the full path with extension included! How can I manage this to get just the name without extension at most simple code?? i mean adapt to some like the structure of `.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension())
```

(But it can't filter formats) not?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is more than one file with the same name but different extensions, e.g. "kitten.avi" and "kitten.mpg"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/index), like following:

```
Dim files As New List(Of String)
files.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(newdir, "*.avi").
               Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)))
files.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(newdir, "*.flv").
               Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)))
files.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(newdir, "*.mpg").
               Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)))

ListBox3.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray)
```